# How to center slideshow images in different sizes within a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have set up a slideshow with jQuery Cycle but am having an issue with centering all my images in different sizes. The images with smaller width are showing on the left inside the div and the images with smaller height is showing on the top inside the div. I tried margin: 0 auto; display: block; text-align: center; but nothing seems to work. I tried setting a min-width or min-height, but it's still not working. It could be something simple that I'm overlooking, or could it be that the jQuery is conflicting with the CSS? Any tips would be very grateful. Here's a sample of what I mean: http://jiyongart.com/Test-centerImage

My HTML:

```
<div id="slideshowWrapper">
 <div id="slideshowImages" class="slideshow">
  <img src="image1.jpg" width="530" height="530"/>
  <img src="image2.jpg" width="530" height="530"/>
  <img src="image3.jpg" width="530" height="530"/>
  <img src="image4.jpg" width="395" height="530"/>
  <img src="image5.jpg" width="530" height="106"/> 
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#slideshowWrapper {
height: 586px;
width: 730px;
position: relative;
float: left;
padding-top: 55px;
text-align:center;
color: #999;
}
#slideshowImages {
background-color: #FFF;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #A1A1A1;
position: relative;
width: 530px;
margin: 0 auto;
top: 0;
text-align: center;
}
#slideshowImages img {
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
text-align: center;
min-width: 395px;
    max-height: 106px
}
.slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
position: absolute;
overflow: visible;
text-align: center;
}
```

jQuery Cycle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.slideshow').cycle({
fx: 'fade', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
speed: 1000, 
timeout: 10000, 
next:   '.slideshow', 
pause:   1,
pager:  '#thumbnavigator',
slideExpr: 'img',
before: function() {  
        $('#caption').html(this.alt); 
          },

// callback fn that creates a thumbnail to use as pager anchor 
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
    return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="40" height="40" /></a></li>';
 }
 });
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6kf4m/)

Comment: seems to be very complicated with the galery you are using cause this gallery is overwriting position and inline-stylings. also in your code there is many times used the id="slideimage" an id can only be used once (use classes instead)

Comment: Thanks Caramba for the JSFiddle. I cleaned up the code and removed the id="slideimage" and other unnecessary jQuery script. Updated JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bdesign/6kf4m/5/)

If the jQuery Cycle is overwriting the position, is there a way to fix this inside the jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to center all image for each size like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/fw9qg/

```
.slideshow
{
    width: 530px;
    height: 530px;
    background-color: silver;
    text-align: center;
}
.slideshow img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.slideshow:after {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: "";
    height: inherit;
}
```

Like this the images will always be in the center of the `.slideshow` element.

Comment: Thanks Nico. Unfortunately, the CSS you suggested did not work. Please have a look at the lines 26-41 in the CSS box here: http://jsfiddle.net/bdesign/6kf4m/5/

I've inserted your CSS, but it's not working. As @caramba was saying, could the jQuery be causing the conflict?

Comment: yes, you are right @bdesign. the problem is, that the image are beeing set to `position: absolute`. My above solution can just handle static/relative images.